# 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform' Error

Tags: asp.net, .net-framework-version

I want to downgrade target framework of asp.net application from 4.5 to 4.0. I have done this in VS2013 successfully but unable to do this in VS2015 and as well as VS2013 also. I have installed 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform' from nuget but it gives me error of some dependency.

Comment: First, tell us what the error message is exactly...

Comment: *I have done this in **VS2013** successfully* But  *unable to do this in VS2015 and as well as **VS2013***